# Change attribute in Kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, kivy, kivy-language

So I'm new to Kivy and Python OOP in this case I wanna pass something from method to an **init**, this is my code

```
class MyLayout3(Screen):
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super().__init__()
    self.gd = GridLayout()
    self.gd.cols=1
    self.tab = Label(halign="center", valign="middle",text='hmm')
    self.gd.add_widget(self.tab)
    self.add_widget(self.gd)
def showTable(self,data):
    #change to string
    print(data)
    MyLayout3().tab.text = data
```

in my .kv file in this class I only have :

```
<MyLayout3>:
    name:'third'
```

lets say, when I'm printing data from showTable, it works fine, but when I'm trying to pass it to **init**, it will be nothing (Blank) but the screen changes, Im working kivy so I think I could use some help with people who get used to it

Comment: You don't "pass values from methods to `__init__`", that's just not a thing. Do you just want `self.tab.text = data`, to change the `next` attribute of the `tab` attribute of the current instance?

Comment: yes, sorry about that, I am a beginer in OOP, can u tell he how t do that?

Comment: `self.tab.text = data`

Comment: That's still display 'hmm' (not changed)

Comment: OOP-wise that's what you have to do. I don't know kivy in particular to be able to say what it requires to notice that the label has updated.